# Testes de interface automatizados com o Jenkins

Tags: testes, jenkins, integração-contínua

Estou utilizando `Casper.js` para testar a interface da minha aplicação e desejo integrar com o `Jenkins`, porém num dos testes é necessário fazer o upload e download de arquivos (.xlsx e .zip). 
Como eu torno "acessível" para o Jenkins fazer o upload destes arquivos? É possível fazer o download de arquivos e abri-los (desejo conferir os resultados)?

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e manda um pouco mais de informação! O upload é uma funcionalidade ou você precisa plantar o arquivo no disco do servidor? Há necessidade de autenticação para o upload ou para o download? Caso sim é uma sessão web ou uma autenticação http simples apenas no servidor web? Qual SO do Jenkins slave e da aplicação? Por que o upload e o download não são feitos pela ferramenta de teste de interface?

Comment: Pode-se parametrizar o Jenkins com o upload de arquivos. Ao editar o Job marque o checkbox de "Este build é parametrizado", depois clique em "Adicionar Parâmetro" e escolha "Parâmetros de arquivos". Depois ao construir com parâmetros é possível fazer upload do arquivo a ser utilizado pelo job do jenkins.